# How do I wait for a java timer to finish

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, timer

I have a java swing GUI in which I'm trying to implement a countdown timer. I have a series of tasks that each need to run sequentially inside a for-loop. I've been able to successfully use a swing timer to do the countdown timer, but once I try and put it in a loop I can't get it to update without freezing the GUI.

Here's an SSCCE of what I currently have working. The basic problem is this example run three 30 second timers in parallel. What I want to do is run three 30 second timers sequentially or in other words it should wait for one timer to finish before beginning the next. Everything I've done to try and wait for the timer to finish makes the GUI freeze.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingTester extends JFrame {
  public SwingTester() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    // Add the components
    jLblTimer = new JLabel("00:30");
    jLblSet = new JLabel("Set #1");
    jBtnStart = new JButton("Start!");
    jBtnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {jBtnStartActionPerformed(evt);}
    });
    // Add the labels
    panel.add(jLblTimer); panel.add(jLblSet); panel.add(jBtnStart);
    pack();
  }
  private void jBtnStartActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    for (int ss=0; ss<3; ss++) {
        // Change the set name
        jLblSet.setText("Set #" + Integer.toString(ss+1));
        // Setup the counter to begin the countdown
        counter = 30;
        timer = new Timer(1000, startCycle());
        timer.start();
        // I want to wait here until the timer is done, nothing I've done
        // works without freezing the GUI.
    }
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        new SwingTester().setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }
  private Action startCycle() {
    return new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new ClockTask(null).execute();
        }
    };
  }
  class ClockTask extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {
  private Callback callback;
  public ClockTask(Callback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
  }
  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
    if (counter >= 0) {
      int millis = counter*1000;
      String time = String.format("%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) -
        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))
        );
      publish(time); // call publish which will call process() method in EDT
      counter--;
    } else {
      // this.callback.call();
      this.callback.notify();
      timer.stop();
    }
    return(null);
  }
  @Override
  protected void process(List<String> times) {
    String lastTime = times.get(times.size()-1);
    jLblTimer.setText(lastTime); // just update ui with lastTimer, ohters are ignorable 
  }
  @Override
  protected void done() {
    super.done();
  }

  // private interface Callback {
  //   void call();
  // }
  }
  private javax.swing.JLabel jLblTimer;
  private javax.swing.JLabel jLblSet;
  private javax.swing.JButton jBtnStart;
  private javax.swing.Timer timer;
  private int counter;

}
```

I've also tried using the sleep function to just wait until the countdown finishes, but this stops the GUI from updating.
Any suggestions are most welcome. As you can probably tell from my code I'm not a programmer.

Comment: *"Here's a sample of my code"* For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks for the suggestion. I erred and just had an SE (Short Example). I've updated my code so that it is an SSCCE.

Comment: An SSCCE of a run-time error would not have `16 errors` on compilation. :(

Comment: Thanks again @AndrewThompson. I forgot to add the last 5 lines of code. It compiles okay for me now using javac 1.7.0_02

Comment: It shows an (odd) count-down here that seems to get faster in later runs.  What is it *supposed* to do?

Comment: @AndrewThompson, it should change the `jLblSet` to Set #1 and then run then countdown timer. Once the timer has completed it should go to the next set and change `jLblSet` to Set #2, etc... As you can see it seems to be running all 3 timers at once. I can't quite figure out how to make it wait for the timer to finish without freezing the GUI.

Answer (score 3):

Below is how you need to change your SwingWorker

```
class ClockTask extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

    private Callback callback;

    public ClockTask(Callback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        if (counter >= 0) {
            int millis = counter*1000;
            String time = String.format("%02d:%02d", 
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - 
                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))
            );

            //jLblTimer.setText(time); // dont update UI in backgroudn thread
            publish(time); // call publish which will call process() method in EDT

            counter--;
        } else {
            this.callback.call();
        }
        return(null);
    }

    /*
     * this  method will be called in EDT and will not freeze your UI ;)
     */
    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> times) {
        String lastTime = times.get(times.size()-1);
        jLblTimer.setText(lastTime); // just update ui with lastTimer, ohters are ignorable 
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        super.done();
    }

    private interface Callback {
        void call();
    }

}
```

You should spend few more time with the JavaDoc of [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

Comment: @Kowser I can't find much information on using "private Callback callback;" I've edited my code to incorporate your changes, thanks for those. However, it still runs through the for-loops without stopping and I then appear to have 3 timers running simultaneously.

Comment: i tried to make a improved solution for you, but it is hard to understand from your code & last comments (`it still runs through the for-loops without stopping and I then appear to have 3 timers running simultaneously`), what you wanted to do actually.

Comment: @Kowser, thanks again for taking the time to help me out. What I'm trying to do is in the `jBtnStartActionPerformed()` function run through a for-loop 3 times. Each time through the loop the countdown timer should start and then it should wait until it has finished to begin the next countdown timer. Right now it's not waiting until the timer finishes and I can't seem to figure out how to do that without freezing the GUI.

Comment: Hi, I tried to investigate the code, i try to compile it, and it come up with at least 10 errors, and could not resolve those :(

Comment: I am not asking for full code, but at least something which can be compiled, or at least something conceptual. may be you can put whole class

Comment: @Kowser the code that is in my edited question compiles for me with version 1.7.0_02 of java. I did update my question per Andrew Thompson's suggestion to have an SSCCE.

Comment: @Kowser, thanks again for being willing to take a look at this.

Comment: @camickr I've updated my question with an SSCCE and Kowser's updated `SwingWorker`. I still can't see to get it to work without freezing the GUI or having it run without stopping.

Answer (score -2):

There're several ways to do so. Normally you can create an object, pass it to the background work, after the background work finishs, it use the object to tell you the result and let you do the rest of work.

```
private class ClockTask extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

    private Callback _callback;

    public ClockTask(Callback callback) {
        this._callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        if (counter >= 0) {
            int millis = counter*1000;
            String time = String.format("%02d:%02d", 
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - 
                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))
            );
            jLblTimer.setText(time);
            counter--;
        } else {
            this._callback.notify();
        }
        return(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 for updating the label (assuming jlbTimer is a JLabel) in the background thread: the whole point of the SwingWorker is to cleanly separate the threads and manage the communication from background --> EDT

Comment: @jeffrey-zhao, this was probably my mistake. I did not post a proper SSCCE for you to look at. I've updated my code so that it is an SSCCE I'd still welcome any suggestions.